# eigenvalues of transformed Hessian

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let us define the vector $\mathbf y$ by $y_i := \exp(x_i)$, with $\mathbf x = (x_i)\in \mathbb{R}^N$, and $f : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,

$$\displaystyle f\left(\mathbf x(\mathbf y)\right) := \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^T Q \mathbf{x}$$ (with $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ symmetric and positive definite). Finally, suppose $(\lambda_k,\mathbf{v}_k)$ is the $k$-th eigenpair of $Q$. According to my (hopefully correct) derivation,

$$ \left[ \nabla^2_{\mathbf{y,y}} f(\mathbf x(\mathbf y)) \right]_{m,n} := \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_m \partial y_n} = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle \frac{Q_{m,n}}{y_m \, y_n}, \; \mathrm{if} \; m \ne n \\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{y_m^2} \left( Q_{m,m} - \sum^{N}_{j=1,j\ne m} Q_{m,j} \log y_j \right), \; \mathrm{if} \; m=n.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

If we fix the $y_m$'s (we consider them constant), then the Hessian elements are linear combinations of the entries of $Q$. How can I write out the eigenpairs of the Hessian of $f$ (at some fixed $\mathbf y$) in terms of $(\lambda_k,\mathbf{v}_k)$?

Comment: what is exactly $\nabla_{y,y}^2f(x)$? is it $\nabla_{x,x}^2f(y(x))$?

Comment: it is $\nabla^2_{y,y}f(x(y))$

Comment: @Surb tried to work out the $N=2$ case with Mathematica, but I could not find a simple relationship between the eigenvalues of $\nabla^2_{\mathbf{yy}} f$ and those of $Q$...